# Failure to xsl transform on repeating node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML that has 1 sales order and in that sales order is 3 sales order lines. The output I am after is a table such as

```
|Line No | Description | Qty 
-----------------------------
|     1  | Product A   | 5
|     2  | Product B   | 10
|     3  | Product C   ! 7
-----------------------------
```

However what I achieve is

```
|Line No | Description | Qty 
-----------------------------
|     1  | Product A   | 5
|     1  | Product A   | 5
|     1  | Product A   | 5
-----------------------------
```

I include my XML input and my XSL in full (sorry if I have supplied too much text)

Can any one spot my error or advise a way forward?

xml Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOQrySurcharge>
    <SalesOrders Language="05" Language2="EN" CssStyle="" DecFormat="1" DateFormat="01" Role="01" Version="6.1.083" OperatorPrimaryRole="   ">
    <Order>
      <CustomerPoNumber>7000654438</CustomerPoNumber>
      <SalesOrder>003411</SalesOrder>

    </Order>
  </SalesOrders>
  <SorDetail Language="05" Language2="EN" CssStyle="" DecFormat="1" DateFormat="01" Role="01" Version="6.1.025" OperatorPrimaryRole="   " xmlns:SALARE="SALARE" xmlns:SALSLS="SALSLS" xmlns:TBLART="TBLART" xmlns:SALBRN="SALBRN" xmlns:TBLCUR="TBLCUR">
    <SalesOrder>003411</SalesOrder>
    <CustomerName>Siemens</CustomerName>

    <HeaderText>
    </HeaderText>
    <SalesOrderLine>
      <Merchandise>
        <SalesOrderLine>   1</SalesOrderLine>
        <MStockCode>11</MStockCode>
        <MStockDes>Low Temp SG Surcharge</MStockDes>
        <MShipQty>       4.100</MShipQty>
        <MPrice>        121.72000</MPrice>
        <OrderLineValue>          499.05</OrderLineValue>

      </Merchandise>
    </SalesOrderLine>
    <SalesOrderLine>
      <Merchandise>
        <SalesOrderLine>   2</SalesOrderLine>
        <MStockCode>1</MStockCode>
        <MStockDes>Grey Iron Surcharge</MStockDes>
        <MShipQty>       0.264</MShipQty>
        <MPrice>        137.63000</MPrice>
        <OrderLineValue>           36.33</OrderLineValue>

      </Merchandise>
    </SalesOrderLine>
    <SalesOrderLine>
      <Merchandise>
        <SalesOrderLine>   3</SalesOrderLine>
       <MStockCode>13</MStockCode>
        <MStockDes>Ferritic SG + Mo Surcharge</MStockDes>
       <MShipQty>      15.155</MShipQty>
        <MPrice>        155.07000</MPrice>

      </Merchandise>
    </SalesOrderLine>
  </SorDetail>
</SOQrySurcharge>
```

xsl Script

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Mestect Usage E-mail</title>
                <style>
            body {
            }

            h1 {
                text-align: left;
                color: #221076;
                font-size: 40px;
                font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .def-container {
                 border: 2px solid black;
                margin: 0 0 3px 0;
                width: 70%;
                background-color: #FFA500;
            }

            .heading {
                display: inline;
                color: black;
                font-size: medium;
                font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .headingvalue {
                display: inline;
                color: black;
                font-size: medium;
                font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            }

                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <p> The following orders have been created by dataswitch in Syspro Company R</p>
                <h1>Auto created Material Surcharges</h1>
                <div class="def-container">
                    <div class="heading">Customer Purchase Order: </div>
                    <div class="headingvalue">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//CustomerPoNumber" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="heading">Customer: </div>
                    <div class="headingvalue">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//CustomerName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="heading">Syspro Order: </div>
                    <div class="headingvalue">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//SalesOrder" />
                    </div>
                    <table border="1">
                    <tr>

                        <th>Surcharge Type</th>
                        <th>Surcharge Amount</th>
                        <th>Tonnes</th>
                        <th>Line Value</th>

                    </tr>

                     <xsl:for-each select="//Merchandise">

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="//MStockDes" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="//MPrice" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="//MShipQty" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="//OrderLineValue" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>



                    </table>
                </div>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally, the transform result

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mestect Usage E-mail</title>
    <style>
            body {
            }

            h1 {
                text-align: left;
                color: #221076;
                font-size: 40px;
                font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .def-container {
                 border: 2px solid black;
                margin: 0 0 3px 0;
                width: 70%;
                background-color: #FFA500;
            }

            .heading {
                display: inline;
                color: black;
                font-size: medium;
                font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .headingvalue {
                display: inline;
                color: black;
                font-size: medium;
                font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            }

                </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> The following orders have been created by dataswitch in Syspro Company R</p>
    <h1>Auto created Material Surcharges</h1>
    <div class="def-container">
      <div class="heading">Customer Purchase Order: </div>
      <div class="headingvalue">7000654438</div>
      <div class="heading">Customer: </div>
      <div class="headingvalue">Siemens</div>
      <div class="heading">Syspro Order: </div>
      <div class="headingvalue">003411</div>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Surcharge Type</th>
          <th>Surcharge Amount</th>
          <th>Tonnes</th>
          <th>Line Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Low Temp SG Surcharge</td>
          <td>        121.72000</td>
          <td>       4.100</td>
          <td>          499.05</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Low Temp SG Surcharge</td>
          <td>        121.72000</td>
          <td>       4.100</td>
          <td>          499.05</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Low Temp SG Surcharge</td>
          <td>        121.72000</td>
          <td>       4.100</td>
          <td>          499.05</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please reduce the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve]

Comment: Ok not seen that link before thank you.  As a newbie I have always been scared of leaving out the important bit ..sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider replacing the `<xsl:for-each>` with an additional template that matches *Merchandise* node. And use `normalize-space()` to remove the extraneous spaces in node text values

Updated **XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/SOQrySurcharge">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Mestect Usage E-mail</title>
        <style>body { } h1 { text-align: left; color: #221076; font-size: 40px; font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; } .def-container { border: 2px solid black; margin: 0 0 3px 0; width: 70%; background-color: #FFA500; } .heading { display: inline; color: black; font-size: medium; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; } .headingvalue { display: inline; color: black; font-size: medium; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; }</style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>The following orders have been created by dataswitch in Syspro Company R</p>
        <h1>Auto created Material Surcharges</h1>
        <div class="def-container">
          <div class="heading">Customer Purchase Order:</div>
          <div class="headingvalue">
            <xsl:value-of select="SalesOrders/Order/CustomerPoNumber" />
          </div>
          <div class="heading">Customer:</div>
          <div class="headingvalue">
            <xsl:value-of select="SorDetail/CustomerName" />
          </div>
          <div class="heading">Syspro Order:</div>
          <div class="headingvalue">
            <xsl:value-of select="SalesOrders/Order/SalesOrder" />
          </div>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>Surcharge Type</th>
              <th>Surcharge Amount</th>
              <th>Tonnes</th>
              <th>Line Value</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="SorDetail/SalesOrderLine" />
          </table>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Merchandise">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(MStockDes)" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(normalize-space(MPrice),'#0.##')" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(normalize-space(MShipQty),'#0.##')" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:if test="OrderLineValue">
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(normalize-space(OrderLineValue),'#.##')" />
        </xsl:if>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output **XML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mestect Usage E-mail</title>
    <style>body { } h1 { text-align: left; color: #221076; font-size: 40px; font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; } .def-container { border: 2px solid black; margin: 0 0 3px 0; width: 70%; background-color: #FFA500; } .heading { display: inline; color: black; font-size: medium; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; } .headingvalue { display: inline; color: black; font-size: medium; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>The following orders have been created by dataswitch in Syspro Company R</p>
    <h1>Auto created Material Surcharges</h1>
    <div class="def-container">
      <div class="heading">Customer Purchase Order:</div>
      <div class="headingvalue">7000654438</div>
      <div class="heading">Customer:</div>
      <div class="headingvalue">Siemens</div>
      <div class="heading">Syspro Order:</div>
      <div class="headingvalue">003411</div>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Surcharge Type</th>
          <th>Surcharge Amount</th>
          <th>Tonnes</th>
          <th>Line Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Low Temp SG Surcharge</td>
          <td>121.72</td>
          <td>4.1</td>
          <td>499.05</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Grey Iron Surcharge</td>
          <td>137.63</td>
          <td>0.26</td>
          <td>36.33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ferritic SG + Mo Surcharge</td>
          <td>155.07</td>
          <td>15.16</td>
          <td />
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you not only explained my problem, but also answer I had not got around to ask, which was about the spaces. Thank you for take the extra trouble. Btw the way can you quickly proved the xsl to round the decimals to 2 places.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. As for rounding in XSLT 1.0, look into `format-number()` function which I show in update here. Notice use of `<xsl:if>` to avoid the NaN result for missing values.

Answer (score 2):

You've made liberal use of expressions such as `//Merchandise`. The leading `//` causes an absolute selection from the root of the input document, whereas you want a relative selection from the current element. Without looking at all the detail, the first thing to do is to cut out the spurious leading "//" on all these expressions.

Comment: The issue is really the child nodes... but yeah, the double slash all over the place is the problem.

Comment: Ok sorry was copied from an example so do // mean "from the root node" and / mean from one node down I take it?

Comment: Please read the spec, or a tutorial. Don't try to learn a language by guessing the semantics from examples, it's an absurdly inefficient process.

Answer (score 0):

The `//` in your xpath queries returns a send of nodes. `<xsl:value-of` is only looking at the first element.  What is happening is you are returning the first element by name that for each `Merchandise`.  You need to change your xpath queries to be relative such as below.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Merchandise">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="./MStockDes" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="./MPrice" />
        </td>
```